# PGP solution for Mac that doesn't store keys on my system?

Tags: pgp

I'm desparately trying to find an OS X app that can:

1. generate PGP keys
2. encrypt files or messages using someone's public key
3. decrypt files or messages using my private key

However all the tools I've tried so far are either so incredibly user-unfriendly (and poorly documented) that I can't get them to work, or they tend to store all PGP keys somewhere on my system (I think 'keyring' is the correct term).
Or they even install all sorts of email plugins or addons or automatic encryption services. I don't want this. For privacy and security reasons, I don't want to leave any traces behind. And I'm not using this for email.

I just want to have someone's public key, and encrypt a random message with it, or receive an encrypted message from someone else and decrypt that.

Either a GUI or command line app would be fine (preferably something that I can install through brew or brew cask). Any suggestions?

Comment: You messed something up with public and private keys. You can only _decrypt_ with a _private_ key, a _public_ key on the other hand is used for _decryption_.

Comment: You must have a public key to which people can encrypt.  You must have a private key with which you would send an encrypted message.  Both of these actions requires you to have a key, which should probably be stored for a while.  You can encrypt and password protect these keys.  Look into **`gpg` from the command line**.  Or, join us on [keybase](https://keybase.io) and use the simple-as-heck CLI tool provided.

Comment: @JensErat Thanks, of course, yes I accidentally mixed those up, fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any readily-build software that is able to do this; it might be possible to program such an application using libraries like [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) (Java, C#) or [the OpenPGP package for Go](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp).

But I can help you with a workaround: GnuPG allows to use a seperate "home directory", and thus also keyring. Doing something like

```
export GPGHOME=/tmp/gnupg
gpg --import [key-file]
gpg --recipient [key-id] --encrypt <file >output   # or decrypt, of course
rm -r /tmp/gnupg
```

will simulate what you're looking for. You could also put this together in a small script (consider using `gpg --list-packets` to `grep` for the key-id) and [use a memdisk](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/23/create-a-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/) to be completely sure not the files are really gone after completion.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I am able to import a PGP key into a temporary dir and delete that later. Protecting keys with a password is not enough, as `gpg --list-keys` still shows the identity information. What I don't understand yet, is what is (in gpg's context) a 'user' or a 'uid' or sender or recipient? The help shows, for example: `gpg -se -r Bob [file]` where Bob is supposed to be a 'user', but what does that mean? I would assume I need to specify the receiver's public key (to encrypt the message), and optionally my own private key to sign it?

Comment: [GnuPG's manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Specify-a-User-ID.html) discusses possibilities to specify user IDs extensively.